# Slick 2.10 with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, slick, slick-2.0

I am new to slick and I need some help with the following error:

```
 java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into "USER_PROFILE" ... Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

The code which causes this error is (the last line of it):

```
def insertUserProfileEvents(events: Seq[UserProfile]) = {
    implicit val session = DbGateway.getSession
    val userProfiles = TableQuery[UserProfileTable]
    (userProfiles ++= events).run
}
```

How do I make the error being more informative?
Maybe I should look for logs in postgres itself?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all that's need to be done is surrounding the exception throwing lines with Scala's Try:

```
def insertUserProfileEvents(events: Seq[UserProfile]) = {
    implicit val session = DbGateway.getSession
    val userProfiles = TableQuery[UserProfileTable]
    Try{(userProfiles ++= events).run} match { case Failure(ex) => println(ex)
}
```